# How to Update Polygon data in SQL server 2008, datatype Geometry

Tags: sql-server-2008, gis, polygons

I am trying to update the column of type Geometry with Polygon data. Following is my query and its giving me strange error. I will be thankful if anyone could let me know what wrong I am doing.

```
UPDATE Test     
set location = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON (148607.181567725 
6818657.60249623, 147539.268528918 6817188.04749019, 144563.526399356 6817136.65513745, 144921.154209564 6818629.77966401, 146841.517476705 6819929.72166114, 148012.482915056 6819763.28604383, 148607.181567725 6818657.60249623)',4326) WHERE id=5;
```

Error in SQL server 2008:

```
    Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24142: Expected "(" at position 10. The input has "1".
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.RecognizeToken(String token)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseLineStringText()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParsePolygonText()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because of one missing open and closing bracket

set location = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON (**(**Polygon coordinates**)**)',4326)